# Configuration issues: Codeigniter and Firebird

Tags: php, codeigniter, firebird, double-quotes

I was integrating Codeigniter and Firebird ... I created a simple database with two tables: CITIES and STATES.

When I run the application, the connection goes OK, but as I try to get all STATES using:

```
$qry = $this->db->get("states");
```

I get the following error message:

> Error Number: -204 Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -204 Table
>   unknown states At line 2, column 1 SELECT * FROM "states" Filename:
>   C:/xampp/htdocs/ci_test/application/controllers/Home.php Line Number:
>   11

I realized that the cause of the problem is the double-quotes at the SQL query. Cause the query:

```
SELECT * FROM states;
```

runs ok.

Has anyone experienced this problem and/or knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like codeigniter quotes object names. In Firebird unquoted names are case insensitive: they are handled as if they are uppercase. Quoted names are case sensitive: they are handled as-is. This means that the table `STATES` can be referenced as `states`, `STATES`, `"STATES"`, but not as `"states"`.

I don't know codeigniter, but you could apply the following solutions:

1. Find a way so codeigniter doesn't quote the object name,
2. Use uppercase in your code `$this->db->get("STATES")`,
3. Change the table so its name is in lowercase.

Comment: Firebird is case insensitive. The double quotation marks in names of tables and fields are not accepted by this DBMS. I realized this in tests I did right now ...

Comment: @FernandoMarcos Firebird certainly does support quoted object names, and if they are quoted they are case sensitive. If you can't use quotes around object names, then you use a dialect 1 database, or you are connecting with dialect 1. Dialect 1 is deprecated (since 2000); you should use dialect 3.

Comment: @MarkRottevel You're right! I was using the wrong dialect! Thanks! Another way to solve this problem, I found, was modifying the class "CI_DB_ibase_driver" (system/database/drivers/ibase/ibase_driver.php) , assigning the value "" (empty string) for the protected property "$ _escape_char". However, I don't know what impact this would cause to the system...

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_states_data() {
    $this->db->select ( '*' );
    $this->db->from ( 'states' );
    $query = $this->db->get ();
    return $query->result ();
}
```

check this code :)

Comment: NeoCodeigniter, It works, but don't solve my problem...I don't want to write my SQL   queries by myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this instead of your existing code

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM states");
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result;
```

Comment: Abdulla, It works, but don't solve my problem...I don't want to write my SQL   queries by myself. Thanks.